# Barcode Scanning using SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner, sap-web-ide

I have requirement to scan barcode / QR-code using SAPUI5. However, I cannot use HAT as HAT is obsolete.

Can anyone help me with the code for the same?

Comment: AFAIK, HAT itself is not deprecated but the _HAT **local add-on**_ is.: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/18/end-of-maintenance-for-hybrid-app-toolkit-local-add-on/. HAT is still supported by Web IDE as an [extension](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8e5c63b6470a4255861c259f3b2d9b41/latest).

Comment: Thank you for the update. However I wanted to know of a method avoiding HAT . I have tried using sap.ndc.barcode, but am unable to scan multiple bar codes within the same image. If you have any code for the same, kindly let me know.